# Why is JPQL/JPA/Hibernate still EAGER loading related records for a ManyToOne/OneToMany despite specifying lazy loading?

Tags: java, sql, jpa, lazy-loading, jpql

I am using JPA to select some data from my database. I have two tables in question, `tracking` and `devices`. The problem I am having, is that when I execute the query defined in the `TrackingRepository` below, it still eagerly loads the Devices and in turn, eagerly loads all tracking associated with the eagerly loaded device.

This is a problem, basically because when I do a query on the recent tracked locations, I select, maybe ten records.

Each of those records selects the associated device record, which then loads ALL associated tracking records for each of the joined devices. There are hundreds of thousands of tracking records split across the devices. So one query turns into a massive load of data, and is killing performance.

In the `Tracking` entity below, when the column for `device` is defined, I specify `@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` - which seems to be ignored. I do not know why. I added the same clause to the Devices table on the tracking column also, which is also disregarded.

What am I missing here?

**Update**
Apologies for my lack of terminology. I should be clear that my queries are entered using JPQL. I know that there is a difference in the layers of the execution with regards to certain things being processed by EntityManager and the likes. My broader question is - "How do you Lazy Load associations when executing queries in JPQL?"

My relevant classes are as follows:

**Tracking**

```java
@Entity(name = "Tracking")
@NamedStoredProcedureQueries(
        {
                @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "nearestCoordinateWithDistance", procedureName = "getNearestCoordWithDistance", resultClasses = Tracking.class),
                @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "randomDistributionByDevice", procedureName = "getRandomTrackingSet", resultClasses = Tracking.class)
        }
)
@Table(name = "tracking")
public class Tracking extends Model {

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "reported_lat", columnDefinition = "BigDecimal")
    private BigDecimal reported_lat;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "reported_lng", columnDefinition = "BigDecimal")
    private BigDecimal reported_lng;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Devices device;

    public Tracking() {
        super();
    }

    public Tracking(Long id, BigDecimal reported_lat, BigDecimal reported_lng, BigDecimal normalized_lat, BigDecimal normalized_lng, Devices device) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.reported_lat = reported_lat;
        this.reported_lng = reported_lng;
        this.device = device;
    }
}
```

**Devices**

```java
@Entity(name = "Devices")
@Table(name = "devices")
public class Devices extends Model {

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "last_seen")
    private Date last_seen;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private String status;

    @Column(name = "current_eta")
    private Integer current_eta;

    @Column(name = "current_dist")
    private Double current_dist;

    @Column(name = "last_distance_calc")
    private Date last_distance_calc;

    @JsonBackReference
    @OneToMany(
            cascade = CascadeType.DETACH,
            orphanRemoval = false,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            mappedBy = "device"
    )

    private Set<Tracking> trackings;

    public Devices() {
        super();
    }

    public Devices(Long id, String name, Date last_seen, Routes route, Integer current_eta, Double current_dist) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.last_seen = last_seen;
        this.current_dist = current_dist;
        this.current_eta = current_eta;
    }
}
```

**TrackingService**

```java
@Service
public class TrackingService
{

    @Autowired
    private TrackingRepository<Tracking> trackingRepository;

    private final static String df = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";

    @Transactional
    public Tracking create(Tracking tracking) {
        Tracking saved = trackingRepository.save(tracking);
        return saved;
    }

    @Transactional
    public List<Tracking> getLastLocations(Devices device, Integer minutes, Integer count) {
        final SimpleDateFormat sdf  = new SimpleDateFormat(df);
        Date                    ts  = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - (minutes * 60 * 1000));
        List<Tracking>      result  = trackingRepository.getLastLocation(device.getId(), ts, new PageRequest(0, count));
        return result;
    }
}
```

**Finally, the TrackingRepository**

```java
public interface TrackingRepository<A>  extends JpaRepository<Tracking, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT t FROM Tracking t WHERE t.device.id = :device_id ORDER BY t.created DESC")
    List<Tracking> getLastLocation(@Param("device_id") Long device_id, Pageable pageable);

    /* This is the one being used */
    @Query("SELECT t FROM Tracking t WHERE t.device.id = :device_id AND t.created >= :time_limit ORDER BY t.created DESC")
    List<Tracking> getLastLocation(@Param("device_id") Long device_id, @Param("time_limit") Date time_limit, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Comment: How do you know that JPA doesn't lazy load these associations. What concrete observation makes you think that?

Comment: @JBNizet - because I am stepping through the codes execution in my IDE. When it hydrates the entity or whatever - the association data is all there, prior to any code taking action on the fetched data.

Comment: It's all there because you look at what's in there. Looking at what's in there calls the method on the object/collection, which lazy loads the state from the database.  Lazy loading doesn't mean "no loading". It means: load lazily, when someone asks for it.

Comment: @JBNizet - these are not code queries, they are inspections - monitors of the current state

Comment: Besides, I can see the query log doing the joins in the first case.